# AWS SageMaker Notebook instance cannot connect to internet

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Trying to understand why my SageMaker notebook instance cannot connect to the internet.

```
# jupyter notebook running conda_python3 kernel

from sagemaker import get_execution_role
role = get_execution_role()
print(role)

'Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.sagemaker.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"'
```

```
# terminal

wget tools.geekflare.com

'unable to resolve host address "tools.geekflare.com"'
```

Any tips on how to debug the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!

SageMaker Notebooks support 3 mode of connectivity,

1. **No VPC**: In this case there is no VPC attached to the Notebook Instance.

   - All traffic goes through SageMaker VPC.
   - Notebook Instance has internet access provided by SageMaker VPC.
2. **VPC + DirectInternetAccess Enabled**: In this case user provided VPC is attached to the Notebook Instance.

   - All traffic to user VPC goes through user provided VPC.
   - Notebook Instance has internet access provided by SageMaker VPC.
3. **VPC + DirectInternetAccess Disabled**: In this case user provided VPC is attached to the Notebook Instance.

   - All traffic goes through user provided VPC
   - Notebook Instance will have internet access only if NAT Gateway is configured in user VPC.

Could you check if there is VPC associated with your Notebook Instance and if yes, is DirectInternetAccess enabled?

You can read more about SageMaker Notebook Instance networking [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/understanding-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-networking-configurations-and-advanced-routing-options/) .

If none of these help, please create an [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285) post so we can get required information via private message to help us debug.

Thanks,

Neelam

Comment: So if user is attempting to run this in SageMaker Studio and there is no notebook yet i.e. Notebook Instance, how does this work?  Did they forget to enable the VPC when they started a Studio Instance?